# make simple program using 'while' and 'do'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

and

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

using 'While' and 'do - while'.

But I have no idea how to approach this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            while (a <= 0)
            {
                while (b <= a)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    b++;
                }
                a++;
                Console.WriteLine();         
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've kept trying to approach like above, but I think It never works ever!

P.S How would I improve my logic about programming? I feel like I'm lack of thinking logically.

Comment: do you need to print this over and over or just once?

Comment: Well the value of `b` is never getting reset.

Comment: While logical thinking is a bit hard to teach [debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) isn't. Also relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k0k771bt.aspx or the documentation that comes with your favorite toolstack / IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I figure this is a homework problem and I usually don't answer them, but I think this may help you understand how to program better, so let me try explain...

Think through what you're trying to do - You want to print 1 star first and then stop at 5 stars and then print the reverse.

So, firstly, **name your variables** to make sense:

```
int numStars = 1;
int maxNumStars = 5;
```

Next, you can loop something along the lines of:

```
while( numStars <= maxNumStars) { ... }
```

Firstly, it lets you understand your problem better, secondly, it becomes readable and debug-able.

Your final procedure can look something as follows:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numStars = 1;
        int maxNumStars = 5;

        // Print the ascending number of stars
        while(numStars <= maxNumStars)
        {
            // Write numStars number of stars to the console using the string constructor:
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', numStars));
            numStars++;
        }

        // Print the descending number of stars
        while (numStars >= 1)
        {
            // Write numStars number of stars to the console using the string constructor:
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', numStars));
            numStars--;
        }

    }
```

Again, not a fan of doing work for a person, but I hope it makes enough sense to actually help you figure out similar problems like this in the future.

---

**Edit:**

For completeness sake, to use loops everywhere, your code / loop could look something like this:

```
        // Declare a variable for writing the stars to the console:
        int numWritten;

        // Print the ascending number of stars
        while(numStars <= maxNumStars)
        {
            // Reset the number of stars written:
            numWritten = 0;

            // Write the stars with a loop:
            while (++numWritten <= numStars)
                Console.Write("*");

            // End the line and increment the numStars variable:
            Console.WriteLine();
            numStars++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank u~!! And it's not my homework problem~! I'm teaching myself with a book.

Comment: Hope it all made sense / gave you a better way of formulating future problems, @user3612935. Don't forget to mark an answer so as to let others who view this know what solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably work in this direction:

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        string s = string.Empty;

        while (a < 5)
        {
            while (b <= a)
            {
                s += "*";
                b++;
            }
            Console.Write(s);
            s = string.Empty;
            a++;
b = 0;
        }
```

Hope it gives you some idea...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways to do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 4;
        while (a <= c)
        {
            b = 0;
            while (b <= a)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                b++;
            }
            a++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (a > c)
        {
            a--;
            while (a >= 0)
            {
                b = a;
                while (b >= 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    b--;
                }
                a--;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

using while loops can be confusing so I came up with this recursive solution (for science)

```
public static void Main()
{
    test();

}

public static void test(string lastOutPut = "",int maxBound = 5,bool goingup = true,int cursor = 0,int maxOutputs = 10){

    if(cursor>maxOutputs)return;
    Console.Write("\n");
    if(goingup){
        Console.Write(lastOutPut+="*");
        cursor++;
        test(lastOutPut,maxBound,lastOutPut.Length <= maxBound,cursor,maxOutputs);

    }else{
        lastOutPut=lastOutPut.Substring(0,lastOutPut.Length-1);
        Console.Write(lastOutPut);
        cursor++;
        test(lastOutPut,maxBound,lastOutPut.Length <= 0,cursor,maxOutputs);
    }


}
```